# how do I generate a cartesian product of several variables using python iterators?

Tags: python, iterator, cartesian-product

Dear all,
Given a variable that takes on, say, three values, I'm trying to generate all possible combinations of, say, triplets of these variables.

While this code does the trick,

```
site_range=[0,1,2]
states = [(s0,s1,s2) for s0 in site_range for s1 in site_range for s2 in site_range]
```

it's somewhat, uhm, clumsy, and is only getting worse if I try to do the same for combinations of more than three variables

Hence, my Python 101 questions:

1. How do I go about rewriting the code above using iterators? I mean, is it possible to have an iterator which would yield the elements of the "states" above?
2. Is it possible to extend this for generating not only triplets, but also 4-plets, 5-plets and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools
site_range=[0,1,2]
[x for x in itertools.product(site_range, repeat=len(site_range))]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> site_range=[0,1]
>>> list(product(site_range, repeat=3))
[000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111]
```

**Edit** As @Glenn Maynard points out in a comment, this is not the cartesian product. For this, you will have to check [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013730/how-do-i-generate-a-cartesian-product-of-several-variables-using-python-iterators/4013768#4013768).

Comment: That's not the cartesian product of [0,1], and that code doesn't even run.  Another incorrect, untested answer accepted over a correct, tested one...

Comment: @Glenn: You are right on both accounts. The code was just intended to illustrate the use of the `product` function. To be honest to example was copied from the documentation of the function.

Comment: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. You need to use `repeat=3` instead

Comment: @gnibbler: Thats what you get from posting python snippets without having an interpreter available for testing. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everybody. In fact I've accepted the very first version of it, which simply said "use itertools.product". Which was enough to get me, like, darn, RTFM before asking.